# Direct selection tool on multiple vectors

Tags: photoshop

Is there a way to select multiple vectors with the direct selection tool.
I have a bunch of buttons with rounded corners and I want to select all 4 points on one side of each vector and scale at the same time. I can do it by using the shift on one vector but not on multiple so far.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but there is no way to change different vector elements at the same time.
The only way to do this is to merge them into one vector shape layer.

Hope this helps.